# Seaborn joint_plot and marginal hists mis-aligned

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn

I'm trying to generate a jointplot for data with linear x and log y. The ranges are -22, -13 for x and 1e-3, 1 for y. The plot seems ok, however the marginal histograms are not correct: at least the one for the x data:

[image]

Here's my code...

```
# Convert observed magnitude to Absolute ...
absMag, pop3Mag, nmAbsMag         = compMags(dir,z)
pop3Fraction                      = haloData[dir][z]['1500A_P3']/haloData[dir][z]['1500A']
pop3Fraction[pop3Fraction < 1e-3] = 1e-3  # Map Pop 3 flux < 1e-3 to 1e-3

data   = np.array((absMag,pop3Fraction)).T # data is list of (x,y) pairs...
df     = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["M", "f"])
x, y   = data.T

# g = sns.jointplot(x="x", y="y", data=df)
g = sns.JointGrid(x='M', y='f', data=df, xlim=[-22,-13],ylim=[0.001,1])
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter)
g.ax_marg_x.set_xscale('linear')
g.ax_marg_y.set_yscale('log')

x_h = g.ax_marg_x.hist(df['M'], color='b', edgecolor='k', bins=magBins)
y_h = g.ax_marg_y.hist(df['f'], orientation="horizontal", color='r', edgecolor='k', bins=fracBins, log=True)

ax = g.ax_joint

ax.set_xscale('linear')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.set_xlim([-22,-13])
ax.set_xticks([-21,-19,-17,-15,-13,-11])

ax.set_ylim([1e-3,1])
```

I'm not sure why the top histogram is not aligned with the data... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind ... on closer inspection there really are more points near -13 than anywhere else... I really need a 2d histogram here to show these nuances.

If someone has a suggestion as to how to make that plot clearly with seaborn I'd appreciate it.